# How do I add a tooltip to a Flash object?

Tags: html

I have a Flash object embedded within a web page that I'd like to annotate with a description. For images, one can use the `alt` and `title` attributes for this, which will result in a tooltip being created on mouseover. Will these attributes work on a Flash object? If not, what can I use?

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully make it a little more understandable. If I have misunderstood your question, feel free to edit it again to represent your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `title="Tooltip text"` for basic tooltips for every element: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/L7Nnv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution here : http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming/279806-display-tooltip-flash-object-post1216810.html#post1216810

Basically you will have something like :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" title="Your Tool Tip" data="" height="32" width="32">
    <param name="movie" value="" />
<!-- The important line   -->
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
</object>
```

I hope this helps.